# Why is the Windows firewall not blocking outbound ports?

Tags: networking, firewall, windows-firewall

I use the following rule to block all outbound communications to remote 80 ports. I want to use this approach to prevent web requests initiated from this computer.

But it seems I still can access web sites over 80 ports.

Why?

[image]

[image]

Comment: That is a wizzard, steps you through nice and easy. after you created your custom rule, get into the firewall console thing. open the standard Windows Firewall window, by going to "Control Panel / System and Security / Windows Firewall". Then, click or tap "Advanced settings".  In there you can see way better what the rule does, and can adjust everything not just a wizzard. Also windows firewall allows all outgoing on the default settings, you MAY want to change that to no outgoing that does not match a rule, but once you do there is a lot to configure as it becomes a real firewall.

Comment: I found my firewall settings is being managed by the McAfee firewall. And the McAfee firewall has a rule which allows all inbound and outbound traffic as long as I am inside the corpnet. I will try again when I am at home network.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, the websites you tried to visit during testing of rule, were running HTTPS.
As far as I know, HTTPS uses different port (TCP 443).

So my answer is:
Try to block port 443 on protocol TCP.
Then test it again.
If it won't work either, I don't know what to do.

Hope I helped.